# Not working- Passing data from Controller to View in a PHP MVC

Tags: php

I'm watching some tutorial on PHP, and I have some problems. 
Everytime I call a variable in view it throws an error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/talkingSpace/topics.php on line 18
```

and

```
Notice: Undefined variable: TotalTopics in /opt/lampp/htdocs/talkingSpace/templates/topics.php on line 36
```

Earlier I would instead of ,for example, $topic->userId, put $topic['userId'], but its not working anymore.

Here is my template/topics.php:

```
<?php
include('includes/header.php');
?>
   <ul id="topics">

                            <?php  if($topics) :  ?>
<?php  foreach ($topics as $topic) :  ?>
                                <li class="topic">
                                      <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                          <img class="avatar pull-left" src="images/avatars/<?php echo $topic['avatar']; ?> " alt="img">
                                        </div> 
                                      <div class="col-md-10"> 
                                               <div class="topic-content pull-right">
                                                      <h3><a href="topic.php"><?php echo $topic['title']; ?></a></h3>
                                                     <div class="topic-info">
                                                                    <a href="topics.php?category=<?php echo urlFormat($topic['category_id']); ?>"><?php echo $topic['name']; ?></a> >> 
                                                                    <a href="profile.php?user=<?php echo urlFormat($topic['user_id']);?>"><?php echo $topic['username']; ?></a>
                                                                  <?php echo formatDate($topic['create_date']);?>
                                                                    <span class="badge pull-right"><?php echo replyCount($topic['id']); ?></span>
                                                    </div>                                         
                                                </div>
                                          </div>
                                    </div>

                                </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
<?php else : ?>
  <p>No topics to display</p>
<?php endif; ?>
                                 <h3>Forum statistics</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Total number of Users: <strong>4</strong></li>
                                <li>Total number of Topics: <strong><?php echo $TotalTopics; ?></strong></li>
                                <li>Total number of Categories: <strong><?php echo $TotalCategories; ?></strong></li>
                            </ul>

<?php
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Here is my Template class:

```
<?php


/**
* Template Class
* Creates a template/view object
*/

class Template 
{
    //Path to template
    protected $template;

    //Variables passed in
    protected $vars = array();

    /*
    * Class Constructor
    */

    public function __construct($template){
        $this->template = $template;
    }


    /*
    * Get template variables
    */

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->vars[$key];
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        extract($this->vars);
        chdir(dirname($this->template));
        ob_start();

        include basename($this->template);

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

?>
```

Here is topics.php:

```
<?php require('core/init.php'); ?>

<?php 
$topic = new Topic;


//Get category From URL
$category = isset($_GET['category']) ? $_GET['category'] : null;

//Get Template & Assign URL
$template = new Template('templates/topics.php');

//Assign Template variables

if(isset($category)){

    $template->topics = $topic->getByCategory($category);
    $template->title = 'Posts In "'.$topic->getCategory($category)->name.'"';
}

if(!isset($category)){

$template->topics = $topic->getAllTopics();
}
//Assign Variables

$template->totalTopics = $topic->getTotalTopics();
$template->totalCategories = $topic->getTotalCategories();

//Display template
echo $template;

?>
```

and my Topic class is here

```
<?php 

class Topic{
    //Init DB variable
    private $db;


//Constructor

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

//Get All Topics

    public function getAllTopics() {
$this->db->query("SELECT topics.*, users.username, users.avatar, categories.name FROM topics
 INNER JOIN users
 ON topics.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN categories
ON topics.category_id = categories.id
ORDER BY create_date DESC
 ");

$results = $this->db->resultset();

return $results;
    }


public function getByCategory($category_id){
$this->db->query("SELECT topics.*, categories.*, users.username, users.avatar,  categories.name  FROM topics
    INNER JOIN categories
    ON topics.category_id = categories.id
    INNER JOIN users
    ON topics.user_id = users.id 
    WHERE topics.category_id = :category_id
    ");
$this->db->bind(':category_id', $category_id);

//Assign Result Set
$results = $this->db->resultset();

return $results;
}


public function getCategory($category_id){
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = :category_id");
$this->db->bind(':category_id', $category_id);

//Assign row
$row = $this->db->single();

return $row;
}

public function getTotalTopics(){

    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM topics");
    $rows = $this->db->resultset();

    return $this->db->rowCount();

}

public function getTotalCategories(){
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
$rows = $this->db->resultset();

return $this->db->rowCount();

}

public function getTotalReplies($topic_id){
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM replies WHERE topic_id = '.$topic_id);
$rows = $this->db->resultset();

return $this->db->rowCount();
}

}
?>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is topics.php line 18 and 36?

Comment: And which is line 18 and 36? Because right now 18 is `/*` which won't give you an error

Comment: I edited the code above with adittional topics.php and topic.php  file.